# Optimal way for curve detection

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, shape-analysis

I am totally new to image recognition and image analysis and have a project concerning detecting a smooth curve on a uniform background (white/black/any color) and then be able to follow this curve until its end. The curve may cross itself but the path that should be recognized should follow along the "smoothness" of the curve. Also, I want to be able to recognize and extract positions (x:s and y:s) of where the curve might turn.  
Since I am new to the area, which seem to be large enough to just become confused, I´m not sure of were to begin reading so any literature or tutorials or whatever is highly appreciated. What I need is some kind of starting point (of course, if anyone know if it is already done somewhere that even better!), what libraries or software to use. Anything is helpful!

Comment: It really depends on the image. Start with morphology and shortest path.

Comment: Allright, thanks! Depends on the image in what sense? Assume that it is just black- and white and not any more complicated.

Comment: Like if the image was noisy for example. If just black and white I would start by morphological thinning so that the path is just 1 pixel wide. Then find a point on the path and look at the surrounding points to get the next point on the path. etc.

Comment: I´ll look into that, sounds like a sound way to begin. Thanks @geometrikal